# appending to a directory in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, copy

I would like to append new files to an existing directory in terminal. So I'm using :

```
cp -r pathtodirectory/directory/ directory
```

but I do not want to overwrite, I just want to update. Any ideas?

Comment: This feature is missing in my cp --version  `(GNU coreutils) 5.97`

Answer (score 0):

```
find pathtodirectory/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c \
    'for f; do ff="directory/$(basename $f)"; if [[ ! -f "$ff" ]]; then echo "Copying $f" && cp "$f" "$ff"; fi; done' sh {} +
```

LIMITATIONS:

- no spaces/glob characters in filenames